# Reducing non-speech noise in a WAV file using NAudio

Tags: vb.net, naudio, wave, noise-reduction

I'm new to DSP. I have searched the internet to no avail for days now. I wrote an WAVE file player using NAudio and other SDKs.  It has a number of features that are working fine.  I just need one more feature before I can release it--that's noise reduction: background, ambient, white.  I think there's a way to implement an ISampleProvider (NAudio interface) into my app, but I need FFT code that I can implement into my class even if I have to port it. Or, perhaps someone can point me to a book/course that would give me the formula to implement as I am not a DSP expert.

As I mentioned above, I've searched the internet for days looking for education on how to do this, code samples, sdks, education of some sort.  I have listen to Mark Health's digital audio courses twice.

here's the code I use to create the audio signal chain:

```
DisposeInputResources()
AudioFileReader1 = New AudioFileReader(Me.FilePath)
SpeedControl = New VarispeedSampleProvider(AudioFileReader1, 100, New SoundTouchProfile(False, False))
SpeedControl.PlaybackRate = 1
AutomaticGainControl = New SoftLimiter(SpeedControl)
AutomaticGainControl.Boost.CurrentValue = Slider_Volume.Value / 2
```

After I implement the code I expect very low or no background noise.  Right now, I have a significant amount of it.

Comment: this appears to be VB.NET, not C#? Please check your tags. Also, if it _is_ VB.NET it looks like it wouldn't compile, unless some of the variables have been declared earlier, outside this sample?

Comment: Yes, this is VB.NET.  I didn't include the code around because developers familiar with NAudio I believe will understand what I am doing without the clutter.

Comment: You may want to check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599743/naudio-fft-returns-small-and-equal-magnitude-values-for-all-frequencies/55765871